# Generating unique sets of numbers from given range

Tags: php

Currently I am using the following script to generate sets of random numbers from a given range in this case it is 1-20. But the sets of numbers this code generates may have the same numbers more than once. What I need is to generate unique random sets from the given range. No number should be repeated in the sets, and all numbers should be used once.

So in this case if I want sets of 5 numbers from 1-20 range, there will be 4 sets, and each number would be used once. Or if I want sets of 4 numbers, then there will be 5 sets with unique randoms.

Basically,  I want to get all the sets with unique randoms from the given range.

How can I get this result?

*Note to admins: I checked the previous posts, although there are similar question in various languages, there isn't a post similar to this one in php. thanks.*

```
<form method="POST" action="">
      <label for="Numbers">Numbers</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="sets" name="sets" value="numbersets"><br />
   <p><input type="submit" value="submit"/></p>
</form>

<?php
function Numbers($min_number, $max_number, $amount_of_numbers)
{
    $range = range($min_number, $max_number);
    shuffle($range);
    $numbers_array = array_slice($range, 0, $amount_of_numbers);
    natsort($numbers_array);
    return array_values($numbers_array);
}

if (isset($_POST['sets'])) {
        echo "<h2>Sets</h2>";
  $number_set = array();
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) { 
            $number_set = Numbers(1, 20, 5);  
            echo implode(",", $number_set) . "<br />";
        }
}


?>
```

Comment: Not really clear. You want X random numbers divieded in Y parts with no duplicates?

Comment: yes, exactly. thanks. It should be done randomly though.

Comment: and it will always be divisible in Y parts. there won't be a case like 4 / 21.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use array_chunk instead of array_slice and prepare the complete multidimensional array in the function.

Then pass it back and echo each subarray.

```
function Numbers($min_number, $max_number, $amount_of_numbers)
{
    $range = range($min_number, $max_number);
    shuffle($range);
    $numbers_array = array_chunk($range, $amount_of_numbers);
    foreach($numbers_array as &$arr){
        natsort($arr);
    }
    return array_values($numbers_array);
}


echo "<h2>Sets</h2>\n";
$number_set = Numbers(1, 20, 5);  
foreach($number_set as $set){
    echo implode(",", $set) . "<br />\n";
}
```

output (example, since it's random):

```
<h2>Sets</h2>
7,10,12,15,16<br />
4,6,8,14,17<br />
1,2,11,13,19<br />
3,5,9,18,20<br />
```

https://3v4l.org/foqIH

Comment: Note that if `$amount_of_numbers` has remainder from dividing the difference between `$min_number` and `$max_number`, then the last array will be fragmented, not contains the number of elements declared by `$amount_of_numbers` (sorry for english).

Comment: For example `$min_number = 1; $max_number = 5; $amount_of_numbers = 3`, you will get `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]`.

Answer (score 1):

Generate a random array once, and slice it into pieces.

```
$range = range(1, 20);
shuffle($range);

$number_set = array();
$offset = 0;

for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    $numbers_array = array_slice($range, $offset, 5);
    natsort($numbers_array);
    $number_set = array_values($numbers_array);
    $offset += 5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to generate the entire list first and then split it up.

```php
<?php
function Numbers($min_number, $max_number, $number_of_groups)
{
    // +1 needed because (for example) min: 4, max: 5 -> 5 - 4 = 1, but there are 2 possible values, not just 1
    $size_of_set = (int)floor(($max_number - $min_number + 1) / $number_of_groups);

    if ($size_of_set == 0) {
        // Handle corner cases
        // ...
    }

    $range = range($min_number, $max_number);
    shuffle($range);

    $results = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_groups; $i++) {
        $results[$i] = array_slice($range, $i*$size_of_set, $size_of_set);
        natsort($results[$i]);
    }
    return $results;
}

if (isset($_POST['sets'])) {
        echo "<h2>Sets</h2>";
        $number_set = Numbers(1, 20, 4);
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($number_set); $i++) {
            echo implode(",", $number_set[$i]) . "<br />";
        }
}
?>
```

**EDIT**

Just realized, that you don't need to use `(int)floor(...)` at `$size_of_set = (int)floor(...)`, because all of the numbers are integers -> the calculation returns with integer.